# High number of failed syscalls against httpd

Tags: centos, apache-httpd, kernel-panic, syscalls

A CentOS7 server running Apache HTTPD server (and a Wordpress site) is undergoing regular scanning with [wpscan](https://wpscan.org/).  This results in a kernel panic:

```
Kernel panic - not syncing: audit: backlog limit exceeded
```

I called up `aureport -ts today` and see that there were over 7000 failed syscalls.

```
ausearch --start today -m syscall -sv no --raw | aureport -x --summary
```

returns:

```
Executable Summary Report
=================================
total  file
=================================
Warning - freq is non-zero and incremental flushing not selected.
7678  /usr/sbin/httpd
35  /usr/sbin/chronyd
7  /usr/libexec/mysqld
```

Is there a way to see specific failed syscalls from httpd? I'm sure all of this is related to `wpscan` but I'm curious to see exactly what is happening to cause each individual failed syscall.

Comment: Can you please show us at least some of the output of ausearch?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
aureport --syscall | fgrep httpd | tail
```

Look at the last column on each line, should be a number (e.g. 5432) so take that number and scan the audit log like this:

```
ausearch --event 5432
```

You can see details in a format that is just barely readable, but at least you can get some clue about filenames and what it's trying to access. Each number is a reference to an individual event so you might have to work your way through them.